# Train error with CNN in Tensorflow for recognising images

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am a newbie of TensorFlow.

I am training fire engines and police cars.

I built CNN for recognising it and ran. 
But the result is like below.

Step 0, Loss= 5987622.00000, Accuracy= 0.00000

Step 10, Loss= 0.00000, Accuracy= 1.00000

Step 20, Loss= 0.00000, Accuracy= 1.00000

Step 30, Loss= 0.00000, Accuracy= 1.00000

What is the problem of that?
Please tell me what cause is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your network and the dataset you're using.

Comment: ^ also please provide some code

Comment: I realised that it was completely trained successfully.